# calling child class method in parent class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations, sti

I have rails 4 application and this models

```
class Product < AR::Base

  default_scope -> { where(product_type: self.to_s) }
  after_initialize { self.product_type = self.class.to_s }

end
```

and many others like this

```
class Orange < Product #Apple, Carrot, ...

end
```

if i call in console `>> Orange.new`, the callback `after_initialize` works like expected: it sets instance attribute `product_type` to `Orange`, so `self.class` is determined as `Orange` class like i need

but

if i call `>> Orange.all`, the method `self.to_s` inside `default_scope` is applied to `Product` class =(

So, **here is the question**: how can i use `Orange` class name inside `default_scope` in parent class (`Product`) in case i do not want to write any methods inside `Orange` class (because there are many subclasses like `Orange` and i want to leave everything DRY).

And so on, if i have `Apple` class, it name has to be used for filtering all `Product` with `default_scope` if i call `>> Apple.all` (some kind of polymorphic association)

thank you.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but did you know if you're using [STI](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) ActiveRecord does that for you if you call query methods on the subclass?  `Product.all.to_sql => "SELECT * FROM products"` vs `Orange.all.to_sql => "SELECT * FROM products WHERE type = 'Orange'"`

Comment: @NathanWallace, the result is the same: `SELECT products.* FROM products  WHERE products.product_type = 'Product'`

Comment: That can happen if the subclass (Orange) hasn't been loaded yet - one of the few times where require_dependency is useful

Comment: @FrederickCheung, will not recursive dependency `(Product->Orange->Product...)` happen then?

Comment: No. Orange won't cause Product to be loaded a second time because it will already be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use STI here:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :product_type
end

class Orange < Product
end

# then...

> Orange.all
Orange Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."product_type" IN ('Orange')
```

Ie. don't do the `default_scope` or the `after_initialize`, because Rails already has you covered as soon as you inherit from another model Rails will assume you're using STI and it will add the right thing in the query.

Comment: this is what solved my current problem, so, thank you - accepted, but more generic question is still actual -> how can i write parent class level method (not for instance but `def self. ...`) using child class level method (i.e. child class name inside parent `def self.current_sti_class_name` method)

Comment: There's nothing complex at all about doing what you're asking in this comment, but you won't get there by using the `after_initialize` method from Rails because it closes on `self` and so `self` will always be whatever it was when the `after_initialize` was executed - ie. it will always be the parent class. If you just use ruby then what you want happens automatically: `class Foo; def self.blah; puts self.to_s; end; end; class Bar < Foo; end; Bar.blah #=> 'Bar'`